# Unable to find ChromeDriver class with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, classnotfoundexception

I have my chromedriver executable file in my MacOS Downloads directory. Here's my code when I'm setting up for using Selenium

```
    import java.lang.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    
    
    public class Scraper {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
           beforeTest();
            }
         public static void beforeTest() {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/ngan.nguyen/Downloads/chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.navigate().to("https://www.indeed.com/");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
        }
    }
```

And I got this exception: cannot found the ChromeDriver class

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/http/HttpClient$Factory
    at Scraper.beforeTest(Scraper.java:39)
    at Scraper.main(Scraper.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient$Factory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 2 more
```

I think it was because my path to chromedriver is not correct in the setProperty method. Chromedriver and Chrome versions are compatible. I also downloaded all needed jar files. How do I get the correct path or is it because of something else? (I'm using IntelliJ)

Answer (score 0):

- Path of the chrome driver exe should be full from drive name.
- You can keep driver exe in project folder and use it by giving path as "./FolderName/chromeDriver.exe");

  ```
     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver, "C//chromedriver.exe);
  ```

Comment: I think I gave the full absolute path, because I'm using macOS I suppose it should start at the src directory